# How to get the primary color's text color (onPrimary)?

Tags: flutter

I'm setting my theme this way:

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  primaryColor: themeModel.primaryColor,
  ...
),
```

Yes, is dynamic.

The problem is: if the user set, let's say, `indigo[100]`, some items (like the `bottomAppBar`) has light icons over that light color (so bad visibility).

I thought the items adapt their text color to the given color property but it doesn't seem to work that way.

So, I have to set that property manually. But I can't find the `Theme` property for text color on primary color (named `onPrimary` in material documentation).

What I found is `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary` but it doesn't seem to work well. It's always returning the same color.

I know I can just get the contrast color for the primary color and set it like this:

```dart
theme: ThemeData.from(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
    primary: themeModel.primaryColor
    onPrimary: themeModel.onPrimaryColor
    ...
  )
)
```

But I'm sure Flutter is intelligent enough to autogenerate those properties if you don't pass them... isn't it?

Another thing that I found is `Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color`. **That property is returning the color I'm looking for.** But as its name states, it's supposed to be applied only to icons, not text, even when they would probably return the same black variant.

---

### What I would like to know

**Is it the way it's supposed to work?** Should I write myself the `onPrimary` property? Is it OK for code quality to use the `primaryIconTheme.color` for text colors? **Or am I missing something?**

Comment: What do you mean by how to get and what exactly you want to get? Your questions are everywhere, it's hard to understand what exactly you are looking for

Comment: @FederickJonathan I showed what I found so far (some properties) and, in the end, I said that what I want to know is if I should use any of these methods I showed or if there is a better way (that I'm missing).

About "how to get"... I'm not sure what do you mean... The objective is to get the text color that should be over the primary color (so, if the primary color is a light yellow, the text color should be black, or if the primary color is a dark purple, the text color should be white).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ThemeData is ThemeData.light() which primaryColor and accentColor are set to Colors.blue, Card and Scaffold background are set to Colors.white. There are 3 types of textTheme :

1. textTheme - Text with a color that contrasts with the card and canvas colors. Basically the theme that is used automatically to all Text widget that is a direct child of Scaffold body or Card. (in this case, Colors.black to contrast Colors.white)
2. primaryTextTheme - A text theme that contrasts with the primary color. Used automatically to all TextWidget that is a direct child of Widgets that use primaryColor, for example AppBar. (Colors.white to contrast Colors.blue)
3. accentTextTheme - A text theme that contrasts with the accent color. Used automatically to all TextWidget that is a direct child of Widgets that use accentColor, for example FloatingActionButton. (Colors.white to contrast Colors.blue)

If you change the primaryColor to Colors.white, the primaryTextTheme.color doesn't automatically change value to contrast that.

```
ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.white,
  primaryTextTheme: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.apply(
    bodyColor: Colors.black,
    displayColor: Colors.black,
  )
)
```

Hope this helps you in any way.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't notice the `color` property in `TextTheme`. Even more, I will not use only the color, but the entire style (because `bodyText` has not the same color of `caption`). And the text color is actually being changed automatically according to the color (so if I set a light color, the text color is being changed to black **and its variations**).